# How to automatically populate database tables

Tags: postgresql

I have some tables in Postgres that I want to populate with dummy data.
Is there a tool/utility that can help with this, that?

1. respects constraints
2. respects foreign keys
3. given schema definition (selected tables), automatically populate with data

Answer (score 1):

You could try to read up generate_series() in postgresql, this function could be used to provide a table with dummy data.

```
insert into testscheme.testtable (id, name) 
    select generate_series, 'name1' from generate_series(1,250)
```

This will provide 250 rows in testtable. You can build further on this. For example replace 1,250 with the primary key contraint. For example with

```
nextval('testtable_pk'::regclass)
```

And if you would like the foreign key respected try to use a subselect:
postgresql order by random(), select rows in random order:

```
select MAX(names) from testscheme.names ORDER BY random()
```

If you wrap this all in a function you can make a script to fill stuff :) Hope I could help.

Here is the documentation of generate_series()
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-srf.html

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly what you mentioned but here you can find a python program that (creates and/or) auto-populate tables with fake data. For anyone who is interested, check it out [here](https://github.com/adriano-pinaffo/populate_data) if you want.

[image]